# jQuery get multiple class name and convert them to an array

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have an element look likes

```
<div class="amy mary peter john tom">abc</div>
```

I will use the jQuery to get the class name

```
var classname = $(div).attr('class');
```

Since the result is "amy mary peter john tom", how can I convert this string to array?

Somethings likes `var classname = ["amy", "mary", "peter", "john", "tom"];`

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [string split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function:

```
var classname = $('div').attr('class').split(/\s+/);
```

Answer (score 1):

for Example : you have :  and you want to get the 'class2'

just add this. hope will help this.
         $('div').attr('class').split(' ')[1];